# Steps to apply windows updates to sql failover cluster?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

What are the steps to apply windows updates to a active/passive two node sql failover cluster?  My initial thought was to apply windows updates to passive node/reboot and then failover and repeat process but not sure.  Do I need to stop the db's and sql agent jobs before failover?

sql2014
windows 2012r2

Comment: I don't have time to write up in an answer but read over https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/failover-clustering/draining-nodes-for-planned-maintenance-with-windows-server-2012/ba-p/371713 and do some testing. I'd get as much of this tested using PowerShell and scripts so you can do on one and then move onto the next per the steps outlined, etc. Also look over this too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/125085/service-pack-and-cumulative-update-in-sql-server-f.html and https://www.sqlnethub.com/blog/how-to-patch-a-sql-server-failover-cluster/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to stop any jobs or services to manually failover. Please see the [Microsoft Docs - Perform a Forced Manual Failover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/perform-a-forced-manual-failover-of-an-availability-group-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) on manually failing over.

These are the general steps you should follow for applying any updates to your failover cluster instances:

1. Backup all databases.
2. Failover all SQL cluster roles to Node A.
3. Install the patches on Node B (passive).
4. Restart Node B.
5. Failover all SQL cluster roles to Node B.
6. Install the patches on Node A (passive).
7. Restart Node A

More information on the installing updates process can be found in these [Microsoft Docs - Upgrade a failover cluster instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/windows/upgrade-a-sql-server-failover-cluster-instance?view=sql-server-ver15).